# How to style as css in OpenPdf?

Tags: java, css, spring, pdf, openpdf

I'm migrating from Itext to OpenPDF because of license. In Itext we were able to use String to represent HTML and CSS elements, then just make the HTMLWorker.parseToElementList that works perfectly, but in OpenPDF I didn't find this possibility. I'm trying to insert CSS styles to style my PDF. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? 
I'm having the same problem. Now I'm exploring the possibility of providing the OpenPDF's StyleSheet object to HTMLWorker.